# Why center of RenderTransformOrigin is 0.5,0.5?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I see samples codes where `RenderTransformOrigin` is used, they would have 0.5, 0.5 as the center instead of 0,0.

I tried both and I don't see any differences. Is there a reason why 0.5,0.5 use used as center instead of 0,0?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx), the values of `RenderTransformOrigin` are

> values between 0 and 1 [and] are
>   interpreted as a factor for the range
>   of the current element in each x,y
>   axis. For example, (0.5,0.5) will
>   cause the render transform to be
>   centered on the element, or (1,1)
>   would place the render transform at
>   the bottom right corner of the
>   element.

In other words, 0.5,0.5 places the transform origin in the center of the element, and 0,0 places it at the top left corner. If you apply a rotation transform, the result of the former is a rotation about the element's center, and in the the latter case, the rotation is about its top left corner.

Answer (score 2):

```
(0,0) -> Takes the top left corner.
(0,1) -> Takes the bottom left corner.
(1,1) -> Takes the bottom right corner.
(1,0) -> Takes the top right corner.
(0.5,0.5) -> Takes the mid point.
```